# EntityFramework.BulkInsert: context does not contain a definition for BulkSaveChanges

Tags: database, entity-framework, bulkinsert, dbcontext, ef-bulkinsert

I'm using EF 6.1.3 and installed EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6.

```
context.BulkSaveChanges();
```

gives me an error

> context does not contain a definition for BulkSaveChanges

I'm forgetting a configuration? Reading https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-savechanges I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong package.

See download link here: https://entityframework-extensions.net/download

You want to `Z.EntityFramework.Extensions` package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions/

Comment: BulkSaveChanges() remains not found. Is there any configuration to do? Do context have to extend/implement something?

Comment: Nope, zero configuration, the method `BulkSaveChanges` should be available on your context as soon as you add the package in your reference. If you wish, send us a project here: info@zzzprojects.com and we will look at it (obviously, I'm the owner of this package). Perhaps your project still references the other package.

Answer (score -1):

You can get EFCore.BulkExtensions package then Use it to Bulk Crud with EF. Like This:

```
await _appDbContext.BulkDeleteAsync(List of Object); 
await _appDbContext.BulkUpdateAsync(List of Object); 
await _appDbContext.BulkInsertAsync(List of Object);
```